# Problem in booting from ubuntustudio DVD

Tags: ubuntu

I am new here, kindly help.

On booting from Ubuntustudio 15.10 32bit DVD. It stop by giving copyright line and after sometime EDD error.

I tried booting from Fedora23 32 bit DVD, from which I installed Fedora 23. But now it also not working.

Find the screenshots.
[image]

[image: Screen trying second time]

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the DVD player, same image using the USB player has worked.